# Create a Diagram from Database Information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

I've been trying to look around lots of libraries but wasnt able to find one that could help me, I already looked at diagramo and gojs and lots of canvas libraries that let you draw your diagram from the browser.

Im developing an application that creates a Cause and Effect Diagram from information that the  users type, this information is saved on a database and I need to create a diagram like that from the database its something like this

http://www.fao.org/WAIRdocs/x5405s/x5405s0h.gif

Any good libraries you might know that could help me? Im using ROR as development

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090774/can-you-suggest-me-any-gem-that-can-give-me-er-diagrams-or-any-database-model-di

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with either of these?

I'm doing exactly this with GoJS and it's great - unfortunately the price of that library is high, though.